# Routing Error: Uninitialized constant in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file containing a helper class something like this:

app/classes/myfile.rb

```
Module mymodule
  class myclass
    # blah blah
  end
end
```

I want to use this class in a controller, so I wrote something like this:

```
require 'myfile'

class MyController < ApplicationController

  include mymodule  

  def index
    mymodule::myclass.new
  end

end
```

The route for the controller is defined like this:

```
  match 'mycontroller', :to => 'mycontroller#index'
```

Now for the strange behaviour I'm facing. It works perfectly fine on the first run after the server starts. But when I refresh the page or hit the URL again, I get the following error.

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant MyController::mymodule
```

I cannot make out anything out of the error, nor can I understand why it does not work from the second hit onward only. What's happening?

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, Rails likes to see files containing:

```
module MyModule
```

named `my_module.rb`

Modules are generally capitalized

Also, it thinks that MyModule is scoped under the MyController class, which it is not. You could try

```
include ::MyModule
```

to access it from the top-level scope.

I also don't know if your load paths include your classes directory, so it is probably not autoloading the myfile.rb file in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I changed require 'myfile' to load 'myfile.rb' and it now works fine. I don't know if I solved the problem though. I don't know what is happening. Can someone enlighten me?